# Conditional Poisson Process

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, poisson-process

I cannot reach a correct answer and I don't know why. I am trying to calculate this by conditioning on $N(t)=n$ and I ended up with $e^{-At(z^s)}$. However, the correct answer is $\dfrac{e^{-At(z^s)}-e^{-At}} {1-e^{-At}}$.

Let ${N(t); t\geq0 }$ be a Poisson process of intensity $A$, and let $Y_1, Y_2,, . . . $be independent and identically distributed nonnegative random variables with cumulative distribution function $G(y) = y^s$ for $0 < y < 1$.
Determine $\Pr[Z(t) > z| N(t) > 0]$, where
$Z(t) = \min\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_{N(t)}\}$.

Comment: I've corrected some of your latex notation. I haven't touched on intensity term, is it $A(t)$ or $At$?

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional probability formula, we have:
$$P(Z(t)>z|N(t)>0)=\frac{P(Z(t)>z\cap N(t)>0)}{P(N(t)>0)}$$

In order to find the joint probability on the numerator, let's first find the joint with event $N(t)=n$. 
$$P(Z(t)>z\cap N(t)=n)=P(Z(t)>z|N(t)=n)P(N(t)=n)=(1-z^s)^ne^{-A}\frac{A^n}{n!}$$
Using this, the joint we want can be calculated as below:
$$\begin{align}P(Z(t)>z\cap N(t)>0)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Z(t)>z\cap N(t)=n)=e^{-A}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{((1-z^s)A)^n}{n!}\\&=e^{-A}(e^{A(1-z^s)}-1)=e^{-Az^s}-e^{-A}\end{align}$$

The denominator is $P(N(t)>0)=1-P(N(t)=0)=1-e^{-A}$. When substituted into the overall expression, we have:
$$P(Z(t)>z|N(t)>0)=\frac{e^{-Az^s}-e^{-A}}{1-e^{-A}}$$
I think the answer uses $A(t)$ instead of $A$.